# Calculating decimal places of pi in Python

Tags: python, mathematics

I have written this small program in Python to calculate decimal places of \$\pi\$. I tried to code it as readably as possible, but since this is a bit calculation heavy, it is reasonable to think about performance optimizations.

The program calculates the first root of the cosine function using the [Newton–Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) and computes sine and cosine with the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions). Since the first root of the cosine function is at \$\frac{\pi}{2}\$, the result is doubled before it is printed.

```
# coding: utf-8

"""
calculate decimal places of pi
"""


from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
from itertools import count


c = getcontext()
c.prec = 1000


def is_close(a, b):
    return abs(a - b).adjusted() + c.prec < 2


def newton(x):
    sums = [Decimal(0) for i in range(4)]
    value = Decimal(1)
    sums[0] += value
    for i in count(1):
        value *= x / i
        tmp = sums[i % 4] + value
        if tmp == sums[i % 4]:
            break
        sums[i % 4] = tmp
    cos_x = sums[0] - sums[2]
    sin_x = sums[1] - sums[3]
    return x + cos_x / sin_x


def main():
    x = Decimal(1)
    while True:
        tmp = newton(x)
        if is_close(tmp, x):
            x = tmp
            break
        x = tmp
    print(x * 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @Aemyl for your post. From a quick check of your code, these initial issues jump out at me:

- Using `__name__` entry point as a runner for `main()` function
- Global statements (`c = getcontext()`) outside of `__main__`
- `sums = [Decimal(0) for i in range(4)]` - unused variable `i`
- Function `is_close` naming. Is close to what?
- Using break (twice) instead of a flag variable explaining why you're ending the loop. in main and in newton

Let's go over them, and then look at some performance tuning.

## Entry point as runner

I see this a lot from people who come from C, but `__main__` IS your main already. You should place the content of `main()` into the entry point where it belongs. This is where other programmers will come to understand how your code runs and why it's doing what it's doing. i.e.:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Decimal(1)
    while True:
        tmp = newton(x)
        ....
```

## Global statements

```
c = getcontext()
c.prec = 1000
```

Understanding the import system of Python is important if you want to improve your Python skills. In this case, the modification of the Decimal can be done inside `__main__`, so we now have:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = getcontext()
    c.prec = 1000
    x = Decimal(1)
    while True:
        ....
```

## Unused variable i

The statement `sums = [Decimal(0) for i in range(4)]` doesn't do anything with `i`.
When I look at that line in my debugger, I can see that it's just populating `sums` with 4 entries of `Decimal(0)`. Let's look at it from the performance checker's view:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    19         8         84.0     10.5      0.0      sums = [Decimal(0) for i in range(4)]
```

And now let's convert the loop into a static statement and re-run that to see if it's improved performance:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
============================================================== 
    21         8         55.0      6.9      0.0      sums = [Decimal(0),Decimal(0),Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
```

That's a little better...

## Variable naming

When you're writing code, it's not about you "now" - it's about the "future you", as well as - if you do it professionally - the other coders who will look at your code. Think about how many times you've come back to your code after a few weeks or months, and you ask yourself "who wrote this rubbish?" and "what the hell was I thinking?" - I know I've had that experience quite a few times.

Variable naming is an important part of explaining what your code is trying to do.

So, as an example of throwaway variables, one of the things Python allows you to do, is use `_` as a variable for these throwaway variables. For example, this code:

```
for i in count(1):
    value *= x / i
    tmp = sums[i % 4] + value
    if tmp == sums[i % 4]:
        break
    sums[i % 4] = tmp
```

Let's replace all the `tmp` variables with `_`:

```
for i in count(1):
    value *= x / i
    _ = sums[i % 4] + value
    if _ == sums[i % 4]:
        break
    sums[i % 4] = _
```

Looks better right? Actually no, it doesn't. So `tmp` really isn't a throwaway variable right? It means something. We need to name the variables to explain what they're doing. Perhaps `calc_val` or quickly looking at some notes about the Newton method, it looks like it's calculating area. So perhaps `area` is better? If I'm wrong, sorry, it was a *very* quick look.

## Using Break

Looking at the main, we see break being used to escape the loop. This approach results in spaghetti code. You should cleanly exit any loop using a control variable or refactor it into a function with a return statement.

Original code is:

```
while True:
    tmp = newton(x)
    if is_close(tmp, x):
        x = tmp
        break
    x = tmp
print(x * 2)
```

Let's introduce a control variable and complete the if into an if/else:

```
calc_pi = True
while calc_pi:
    tmp = newton(x)
    if is_close(tmp, x):
        x = tmp
        calc_pi = False
    else:
        x = tmp
print(x * 2)
```

Now we're not using break, the loop will exit cleanly into the print statement.

Ah! But what is this? What do we see?

It's now clear that both paths of the `if` statement perform the same action. Is this an error? Let's make sure the output is the same, then make a change.

```
result = x * 2
print(result)
if str(result) != "3.14159265....0214":
    print("wrong, didn't match")
```

And write the changes:

```
while calc_pi:
    tmp = newton(x)
    if is_close(tmp, x):
        calc_pi = False
    x = tmp
```

And run the code - yes, the result matches. So this proves the paths were equal and we were correct to refactor that code into that final version (above).

We can also perform a similar change to the `newton(x)` code, but this is getting a little long, and you asked for performance enhancements.

## Performance Checking

Running line_profiler (there's lots of examples how on the 'net), we have the following results:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    19                                           @profile
    20                                           def newton(x):
    21         8         55.0      6.9      0.0      sums = [Decimal(0),Decimal(0),Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
    22         8         15.0      1.9      0.0      value = Decimal(1)
    23         8         24.0      3.0      0.0      sums[0] += value
    24      3857       3140.0      0.8      1.2      for i in count(1):
    25      3857     233157.0     60.5     86.2          value *= x / i
    26      3857      13665.0      3.5      5.0          tmp = sums[i % 4] + value
    27      3857      15645.0      4.1      5.8          if tmp == sums[i % 4]:
    28         8          9.0      1.1      0.0              break
    29      3849       4438.0      1.2      1.6          sums[i % 4] = tmp
    30         8         21.0      2.6      0.0      cos_x = sums[0] - sums[2]
    31         8         19.0      2.4      0.0      sin_x = sums[1] - sums[3]
    32         8        416.0     52.0      0.2      return x + cos_x / sin_x
```

Well, value and sums creations still don't look right. Line 23 is doing another static assignment which we can roll into line 21. So, let's change `sums[0]` into `Decimal(1)` and remove line 23.

Line 25 seems to be doing most of the work, but I can see that you're continually recalculating modulo. Let's create a variable storing the modulo result and use that instead.

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    14                                           @profile
    15                                           def newton(x):
    16         8         33.0      4.1      0.0      sums = [Decimal(1), Decimal(0), Decimal(0), Decimal(0)]
    17         8          9.0      1.1      0.0      value = Decimal(1)
    18      3857       2314.0      0.6      1.3      for i in count(1):
    19      3857     152870.0     39.6     87.9          value *= x / i
    20      3857       3353.0      0.9      1.9          mod_val = i % 4
    21      3857       8470.0      2.2      4.9          tmp = sums[mod_val] + value
    22      3857       3670.0      1.0      2.1          if tmp == sums[mod_val]:
    23         8          4.0      0.5      0.0              break
    24      3849       2961.0      0.8      1.7          sums[mod_val] = tmp
    25         8         13.0      1.6      0.0      cos_x = sums[0] - sums[2]
    26         8         11.0      1.4      0.0      sin_x = sums[1] - sums[3]
    27         8        274.0     34.2      0.2      return x + cos_x / sin_x
```

So changes thus far have made it run about 60% better (270604 -> 173982). And changing the `for` loop into a `while` loop with a control variable:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    14                                           @profile
    15                                           def newton(x):
    16         8         31.0      3.9      0.0      sums = [Decimal(1), Decimal(0), Decimal(0), Decimal(0)]
    17         8          9.0      1.1      0.0      value = Decimal(1)
    18         8          6.0      0.8      0.0      do_calcs = True
    19         8          3.0      0.4      0.0      counter = 1
    20      3865       2430.0      0.6      1.2      while do_calcs:
    21      3857     173534.0     45.0     87.4          value *= x / counter
    22      3857       3466.0      0.9      1.7          mod_val = counter % 4
    23      3857       8579.0      2.2      4.3          tmp = sums[mod_val] + value
    24      3857       3994.0      1.0      2.0          if tmp == sums[mod_val]:
    25         8          6.0      0.8      0.0              do_calcs = False
    26                                                   else:
    27      3849       3214.0      0.8      1.6              sums[mod_val] = tmp
    28      3849       2973.0      0.8      1.5              counter += 1
    29         8         16.0      2.0      0.0      cos_x = sums[0] - sums[2]
    30         8         13.0      1.6      0.0      sin_x = sums[1] - sums[3]
    31         8        283.0     35.4      0.1      return x + cos_x / sin_x
```

But as you can see, that slowed it down a little (198274; slower by 24292) although the code is much clearer, and we can now refactor that into a function - because the `break` has been removed (I use PyCharm's Refactor->Extract->Method approach).

Also, we unwrap the `*=` into a full calculation, and reintroduce your original for loop via `count(1)`, primarily because we've wrapped it into a function so it can exit cleanly with a return statement:

```
Total time: 0.191908 s
File: 0908_calc_pi.py
Function: newton at line 14

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    14                                           @profile
    15                                           def newton(x):
    16         8         35.0      4.4      0.0      sums = [Decimal(1), Decimal(0), Decimal(0), Decimal(0)]
    17         8          9.0      1.1      0.0      value = Decimal(1)
    18         8     191565.0  23945.6     99.8      sums = perform_calcs(sums, value, x)
    19         8         16.0      2.0      0.0      cos_x = sums[0] - sums[2]
    20         8         11.0      1.4      0.0      sin_x = sums[1] - sums[3]
    21         8        272.0     34.0      0.1      return x + cos_x / sin_x

Total time: 0.18069 s
File: 0908_calc_pi.py
Function: perform_calcs at line 23

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    23                                           @profile
    24                                           def perform_calcs(sums, value, x):
    25      3857       2152.0      0.6      1.2      for counter in count(1):
    26      3857     162137.0     42.0     89.7          value = value * (x / counter)
    27      3857       2765.0      0.7      1.5          mod_val = counter % 4
    28      3857       7591.0      2.0      4.2          tmp = sums[mod_val] + value
    29      3857       3497.0      0.9      1.9          if tmp == sums[mod_val]:
    30         8          8.0      1.0      0.0              return sums
    31                                                   else:
    32      3849       2540.0      0.7      1.4              sums[mod_val] = tmp
```

Giving us a value of 191908. That's a little slower than the best, but it's cleaner and refactored (variable naming needs some work still). That's about the best I can think of off the top of my head. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks like you invested a lot of time to write it. Can you explain why the line `value *= x / i` runs much faster after introducing `mod_val`? It looks totally unrelated to me.

Comment: Cheers. To know that, we'd have to ask someone more familiar with lower-level compiler knowledge or have the before and after assembly dump reviewed to obtain an answer. I don't know anyone with either skill-set. Maybe someone from the reverseengineering forum would be able to answer it?

Comment: If there shouldn't be a `main` function, then why does the [official documentation for `__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) show doing exactly that?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode in the python standard library, both versions appear: `aifc.py` runs the main routine directly in `if __name__ == '__main__':`, while `ast.py` uses a `main` function. I think I should ask myself how likely it is for another script to import the `main` function and how likely it is to have a bug because the variables I use inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` are in the global name scope. I personally prefer using a `main` function but I wouldn't be surprised if there are good reasons against it.

Comment: @Aemyl Yeah I find it odd to say one "should" pollute globals.

Comment: @Aemyl My guess is that the speed difference after introducing `mod_val` is because their CPU was busier with other things during the earlier run.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode sometimes I notice a significant speed difference between the first run of a script and following runs. For example, when I open the python console right after starting my computer and execute `import tensorflow`, it takes a really long time to load. When I close the console, open a new one and run `import tensorflow` again, it is much faster. I can imagine something similar happening here, but I don't know how to measure that properly.

Comment: @Aemyl Running both the "before" version and the "after" version a few times alternatingly, [I see no speed difference](https://pastebin.com/raw/Xy4Baa3B).

Comment: Relevant (albeit closed) StackOverflow question: [What is the style guideline for if \_\_name\_\_ == '\_\_main\_\_'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23922503)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode That's a contrived example to end the point about launching as a script or operating as a library import. Later on, as Aemyl improves coding, they will write libraries or utilise TDD. If you write C code, you place the entire program logic inside main. For Python, if you're writing a single-executable script, you write the logic in the entry point. If you're writing a library, there is no entry point. If another coder reads your code, they don't want to chase the logic around and lose their train of thought. YMMV, but experienced coders taught me these valuable lessons.

Comment: Actually the `__main__` documentation just got rewritten and expanded for the upcoming Python 3.10, including an "[Idiomatic Usage](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/__main__.html#idiomatic-usage)" section which says *"Most often, a function named main encapsulates the program’s primary behavior"*. And Guido van Rossum [called that rewrite "great"](https://bugs.python.org/issue39452#msg400671) and explicitly advocated using a `main` function like done here.

Comment: The _entry point as runner_ section is plain wrong. Having a main routine is not redundant.

Comment: I think the `while` loop would be clearer as `while not is_close(calc_val, x):` and no need for a `break` or an artificial "keep looping" variable; obviously we should initialise `calc_val` to something reasonable outside the loop (perhaps `calc_val = 0` and `x = 3`).